# iOS 8 Local Notifications Expire

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to have local notifications expire after a certain period of time, say 5 minutes? The best I could do is to check the local notification and do no action if it has "expired", but is there a way to remove it from the notification center altogether?

This is my check:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification     *)notification {
BTLOG(@"Notification: %@", notification.userInfo);
    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:notification.fireDate] < 300) {
        **code**
    }
}
```

But like I said, I would like the notification to disappear from the notification history altogether. This just intercepts the action and blocks it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your post with code you've done so far. I might be able to help then.

Comment: I have updated my post as requested.

Comment: can you add the code where you are creating the local notif. with user info?